# Selenium keys chord dosen't work with Chrome v75

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, key, selenium-chromedriver

My code works ok before v75 appeared. I simulated ctrl+a, ctrl+shift+right, ctrl+right keys.

I found a computer with Selenium driver and chromium v74 and tries jar file on it. All works.
Example of non-working properly code below

```
service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder().usingDriverExecutable(new File("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")).usingAnyFreePort().build();
service.start();
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(), capabilities);
driver.get("https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea");
Thread.sleep(1000);
WebElement element= driver.findElements(By.tagName("input")).get(3);
element.sendKeys("send smth");
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.sendKeys(Keys.SHIFT,Keys.RIGHT).perform();
actions.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT,Keys.RIGHT)).perform();
actions.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a")).perform();
```

last 3 rows don't select text.

> org.seleniumhq.selenium.selenium-chrome-driver 3.141.59
>
> org.seleniumhq.selenium.selenium-support 3.141.59
>
> org.openqa.selenium.webdriver 0.6.1039

The sample of code
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KNI0xTCpJ46fqLk054VhN2g99U12R6Le

Comment: You need to use appropriate version of chromedriver depending to Chrome version - http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads. Mostly if this is not respected everything is fine, but mostly not everytime. Your issue seems to be one of the exceptions.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu all chrome's packages update in one moment. I checked chromedriver was 75 version

Comment: What's the exception? For example, if WebElement element comes as null, none of the actions will be performed.

Comment: there are no error. Just not emulate ctrl key

Comment: Make a breakpoint at the first sendKeys action, debug your code, check variables for anomalies.

Comment: There are no variables in this piece of code. If I downgrade version of chromedriver, all works fine.